# Using less.css and Twitter Bootstrap 3 - mixins not working

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

Alrighty, so I am trying to add classes to my page via css. Below is an example of the less.css file I am writing:

```
.someClass {
    .col-sm-6;
}
```

I swear this worked before, but for whatever reason, my compiler throws an error:

> ".col-sm-6 is undefined"

`Compiler: WinLess`

Essentially I'm just trying to assign the `col-sm-6` class to a div for width/float etc... Please let me know if you can think of any reasons this wouldn't work. 
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you adding your custom LESS?

Comment: @isherwood can you please be more descriptive with your question?

Comment: Not really. Where are you putting your code?

Comment: I have a less css file that compiles into the main style.css. i can confirm other styles are being picked up (like if i put a background color on something, it works, but the col-sm-6 doesn't)... if that makes sense. the less i am using in the example above is just that mixin, essentially "adding .col-sm-6's class/styles to the element"...

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether the Bootstrap LESS file that contains `.col-sm-6` is available when and where you're compiling.

Comment: i see what you're getting at. i swear this WAS working at some point. maybe i was just seeing things. are you familiar with which file contains the "col-XX-XX" variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 makes these class names via a dynamic mixin, so they are not directly accessible as mixins themselves (dynamically generated class names are not currently able in LESS to be accessed as mixins). Instead, you need to call the mixin to generate the code by doing this:

```
.someClass {
    .make-sm-column(6);
}
```